# Maximise the happiness among children

Tags: algorithms

Given N different candies and  M childrens. Each ith children demands for K[i] different candies and will **ONLY BE HAPPY IFF HE GET ALL THOSE DIFFERENT CANDIES WHICH HE DEMANDED.**

Now i want that maximum children should be happy.So how should i distribute the candies to do the same?

I need to find maximum children that i can make happy.

EXAMPLE :

Let we have N=4 candies and M=3 children
Now

1st children require 2 (=K[1]) candies which are : 1 and 2

2nd children require 2 (=K[2]) candies which are : 2 and 3

3rd children require 2 (=K[3]) candies which are : 3 and 4

Then here answer will be 2 as i can at max only make 1st and 3rd child happy.

Comment: Spank them all and send the rotten little ingrates to bed *without* any candy.

Comment: @MJD that was soooo rude..:p

Comment: @MJD And eat the candies yourself :P

Comment: I think your question needs clarification. Do you only want an algorithm that calculates that? Then you can just use a brute force algorithm. Or you want an "efficient" one? (where "efficient" must be properly defined).

Comment: @PedroForquesato I want an efficient one.N can go upto 20,000 and M <=20 .So i dont think bruteforce will work

Comment: @user3001932 How often are you running this algorithm?  Checking the 2^20 can be done extremely quickly with a well written program (think C not javascript).  What is the maximum number of candies a child could want?

Comment: @DanielV at worst he can want all of them .And are u talking of ur algorithm being purposed ?

Comment: @user300192 Actually I'm dumb, the number of candies a child could want is irrelevant, it may be infinity and it won't affect your runtime.  Just build a 20x20 table with a 1 when children are exclusive and a 0 when they aren't and run basic exponential search on it.  It will take you longer to write the program than to run it.  20 isn't that much.

Comment: @DanielV means u mean no need of algorithm u purposed down ? thn could u please easy and correct algorithm ?How to check if children are exclusive or not ?

Comment: @user3001932 You need to understand my answer below to solve this problem.  However, once you understand how to build the graph (or adjacency matrix of the graph), then you can use brute force to search all possible valid subsets.  It will take you longer to optimize the algorithm than to actually run it for 20 children.  Given the extreme density of the graph, a smart depth first search of the children will probably finish in a few milliseconds.  Asking for code is considered rude on this site, because it suggests that you are not trying to understand the problem yourself.

Comment: @DanielV i generated adj matrix .What u mean by bruteforce here to search all possible VALID subsets?Can i ask u what u means by SMART DFS ?

Comment: If $C$ is a set of children, and $g(C, x)$ is the subset of $C$ that don't conflict with child $x$, then, and $f(C)$ is the maximum number of children that can be pleased: $f(C) = \max(1 + f(g(cdr\, c, car\, c)), f(cdr\, c))$, this is very fast to compute when $|C|$ is about 20 and your $g(C, x)$ is much smaller than $C$.  (car c is the first child, cdr c is the rest of the children, it's lisp notation)

Answer (score 1):

Construct a graph as follows:

- Each vertex represents a child
- Two vertexes share an edge iff the children are exclusive in terms of happiness; that is, if there exists a piece of candy that both children want then they share an edge

Now your problem is to find the maximum number of vertices which do not share an edge.  This is called an "independent set".  Unfortunately, this is NP-Hard.  Solving it exactly is not known in polynomial time, but it is a well studied problem so you have options.

The problem of finding the maximum independent set is the same as the problem as finding the maximum clique in the dual graph, so you may see the problem described that way.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_independent_set#Finding_maximum_independent_sets

---

[image: Example]

This is the example from your question.  The 3 vertexes are the circles which represent the 3 children.  The red edge represents that the first and second child both want candy number 2.  The blue edge represents that the second and third child both want candy 3.

The maximum independent set is 1st and 3rd since they do not share an edge.

Comment: Could u please explain how u constructed graph through some example..i didnt get u

Comment: @user3001932 Ok hopefully that helps.

Comment: What would be answer according to u if we have 2 candies and 4 children each demanding for candy no. 1 ?

Comment: Only 1 child can be pleased.  Please don't deliberately misspell words on this website.  It is spelled "you".  Not everyone is a native English speaker, but you should do the best you can.  You aren't the only user here.

Comment: Ohk..Am sorry for mistake .Actually am not able to develop algorithm to do it..:(

Answer (score -1):

This is a greedy algorithm: you have give the candy that they demand in the order of the amounts that they require to be happy (i.e. K[i]). In other words, you should only give candy to a child if you have made happy all the children that demand less, and every time you give candy to one of them you have to give them the whole amount that they require.

Comment: whats the correctness proof of ur algorithm?

Comment: The actual number of candies they demand is completely irrelevant. What matters is how many (and which) other children they demand.  You could have 50 children demanding 1000 different candies (50000 candies) and 2 children that demand 25 candies each, one from each of the other 50 children.  Obviously you would want to pick the 50 children not the 2.

Comment: @DanielV is it going to be correct always ? Could u please provide some algorithm to do the same

Comment: @user3001932 This approach is not always correct, unfortunately.  My above comment is to provide a counter example.

Comment: @DanielV, this is not a counter example. If you apply the algorithm that I propose, if you have N=50000 candies you would give 25 to each of the 2 children that demand 25 and 1000 to each 49 kids that demand 1000. This would cost you 49050 candies, which you have, and you would make 51 kids happy. Only one of them will be unhappy. If you choose to give the 50000 candies to the 50 kids that demand 1000, you make 50 kids happy and 2 unhappy.

Comment: @jordix I think you are misunderstanding the question.  The candies are unique; they are all different.  You did correctly answer the problem for when the candies are all the same, but that is not what the poster wants unfortunately.